# Load vertex animation

Tags: python, animation, keyframes, unreal-engine

I have a vertex animation in text form (deserialized unreal vertMesh). It is a series of units: frame # 0 (vertex#0, Vertex#1 , Vertex#2 .. Vertex#N), frame # 1 (vertex#0, Vertex#1 , Vertex#2 .. Vertex#N)

Can I create keyframes with python from this data?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36902/how-to-keyframe-mesh-vertices-in-python/36915#36915  possibly a duplicate..

Comment: Did these links help with the keyframing?