# How to keyframe mesh vertices in Python and export to fbx

Tags: python, animation, export, keyframes

Hi i just came from reading this thread

[How to keyframe mesh vertices in Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36902/how-to-keyframe-mesh-vertices-in-python/36950#36950?newreg=27bfdbbcbf9843389b269c0d9139d846)

and it was very helpful, however i can't seem to figure out how to actually export the vertex animation after the script creates it.

every time i try to export as fbx no matter what settings i use the model exported has no animation attached.

my end goal is to have a script that creats the vertex animation and then exports it as an fbx, but i cant even seem to get it to export even from the editor.

help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which method from linked thread are you using?  Is keyframing individual verts possible in fbx? Perhaps the shapekey solution is the go.

Comment: Iv'e tried all of the functions from the thread and i cant seem to export any of them as an fbx file with the animation attached