# Insert a key frame on a coordonate in a bmesh

Tags: python, keyframes, bmesh

I am new to this forum and also to bpy.
I would like to insert a series of keyframes but I do not know the data path to use with bmesh, could you help me.
Thank you.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.data.objects['Vert'].select_set(True)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['Vert']
me = bpy.context.object.data
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)
for v in bm.verts:
    v.co.x += 1.0
    #Here I would like to insert a keyframe on each co.x
bm.to_mesh(me)
bm.free()
```

Comment: I suppose the answer here is cannot keyframe a bmesh or any bmesh type, eg  `BMVert, BMEdge, BMFace`  For a blender object to be (potentially)  keyframe-able it must have a `keyframe_insert` method.   Can keyframe vertices. See link above.

Comment: I think you want shapekeys instead of keyframes

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice,
if I understood correctly I must insert key frames directly on the coordinates of the vertices.
The problem that arises is that of a correct call:
`bpy.data.meshes["Vert"].vertices[0].keyframe_insert("#i_dont_know_what _to_call_here", frame=1)`.
To Gorgious, I have already tried the shape keys and the file is too heavy ...

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/235083/15543

Comment: Thanks a lot batFINGER that will do the job.