# Copy keyframe data of vertex to extruded vertices

Tags: animation, vertices, linked-data

I animated a sinewave onto my mesh path with keyframes.
[image]

After extruding the verts, the animation data doesn't get copied to the extruded mesh.
[image]
Only the originals verts before extruding are animated.

Is there a way to keep or relink the animation data on the extruded verts?

Here is the .blend file with the animated sinewave.
[image]

Comment: can u tell us how you animated your mesh? or provide your blend file?

Comment: Keyframes are set in python using the accepted answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36902/how-to-keyframe-mesh-vertices-in-python Instead of also setting the keyframes for the extruded verts with python I want the flexibility of doing it in the GUI with existing operators.